# SOQL query to find Tasks by Subject and Count

Tags: soql, tasks, data

We are trying to find tasks of the same Subject that occupy a lot of records. For example, there might be 4,000 tasks all titled "**Opportunity closing in 3 days**" and we want to find all instances where a single Subject is responsible for more than 1,000 records.

What I want to do is basically this:

```
SELECT subject 
FROM Task
having count(subject) > 1000
```

But this results in a parsing error. Is my syntax just bad, it's more complicated than that, or can this not actually be done?

Comment: I has a try in my environment, and unfortunately you can't group by the Subject field on Task.

Answer (score 0):

It gives a parsing error (MALFORMED_QUERY) because you can only use [HAVING](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm) clause after a GROUP BY one.

Moreover to know which subject is related to more than *N* records, you don't have to COUNT subject, you have to GROUP BY Subject and filter counting IDs since each one identify a record.

So it should have been

```sql
SELECT Subject
FROM Task
GROUP BY Subject 
HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1000
```

Once you got the Subjects, you could have added them to a list to query once again the task with those subjects to get their IDs.

Anyway that query won't work since you cannot GROUP BY Subject.
Reading [Considerations for GROUP BY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_group_by_considerations.htm) you can see that

> Some object fields have a field type that doesn’t support grouping. You can't include fields with these field types in a GROUP BY clause.
> [...]
> To check whether a field supports grouping for standard objects, you can also check the properties for the field in the Object Reference for Salesforce and Lightning Platform

Than checking the reference for [Task Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) you'll see that Subject field lacks of *Group* property. Indeed if you try that query, you'll get

> field 'Subject' can not be grouped in a query call